# Is there a perfect program changing IP to Country(meaning 100%!)?

Tags: ip, geoip

I'm using a software (called GeoIP).

It has a lot of database, and performs better than others.

but, not enough for me.

Corretness of this software is 99%, maybe.

I need 100% accuracy.

Please, let me know the perfect program.

PS. It's ok the program is not free.

Answer (score 2):

Short said, it is impossible. You can tell to which company an IP address was originally assigned, but you cannot know what this company does with that IP address. If they give it to a subsidiary abroad, you have lost.